# No password prompt on lock acreen

Tags: security

I have a 5.0 install that has upgraded to 5.1. since the initial install, I've never had the password prompt come up for getting back into the machine after locking. I verified that I do have locking turned on, and my account requires a password to login.

When locking, the screen will go to a lockscreen (after a long wait), but when I return and move the mouse or hit the keyboard, I'm immediately returned to my running session...no password needed.

While some would call this a feature, I kind need to be able to lock my screen. Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: can you disable locking, reboot your system and then enable it again and check out does it work? I had a similar problem a long time ago and resolve it like this.

Comment: I'll give it try shortly. Stay tuned.

Comment: @Borislav Thanks! It worked!

Comment: glad to see that, I have posted my comment as an answer, can you accept it in order to be visible into StackExchange system that your problem is resolved and what solution did help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable locking, reboot your system and then enable it again and log out. I had a similar problem a long time ago and resolve it like this